# Query Active Directory from HANA Cloud Integration / HCI

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sap-cloud-platform

since HANA Cloud Integration LDAP Adapter supports MODIFY/INSERT only, I would like to ask if it possible to Query Active Directory via Script? Active Directory is already connected via Cloud Connector in my Scenario.

I found some solutions for Javascript, but HCI does not support ActiveXObjects.

Does anybody have an idea how to query AD via HCI?

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw it is possible via groovy script. but its like 500 lines of code and not possible to publish it to the public. i would not recommend it again if there are other options (e.g. put a nightly csv-file to a share and fetch it from a network path instead of fetching from AD)